# Applying Same Style to Multiple IDs with Same Words

Tags: css, wordpress

I'd like to know if there's a way to apply the same styles to IDs that start with the same workds.

For example, I have #youtube_gallery_item_1, #youtube_gallery_item_2,....and the number keeps increasing, so I can't add a new ID every time I add a new item. FYI, I'm working with Wordpress and YouTube SiimpleGallery plugin.

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "starts with" selector in CSS3.

```
div[id^=youtube_gallery_item] {

}
```

Note that this doesn't work in IE8 and below.

What would be a better idea would be to assign all of your `#youtube_gallery_items` a class, and then assign styles to that class. I'm sure that the plugin that you're using is doing this. Look at the source code, and if you see that they all have the same class, use:

```
.name-of-the-class {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
[id^="youtube_gallery_item"] {
    color: skyblue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9Ya8/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a class

```
.youtube_gallery_item {
    background: ;
    width: ;
    ...
}
```

Its compatible with all browsers and is the easiest way to get around.

```
<div id="youtube_gallery_item_1" class="youtube_gallery_item"></div>
<div id="youtube_gallery_item_2" class="youtube_gallery_item"></div>
<div id="youtube_gallery_item_3" class="youtube_gallery_item"></div>
```